# docker-compose build takes a very long time is there a verbose/debug log I can enable when building?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

It gets stuck on "Building blahblah" for around 18+ minutes sometimes longer...

After waiting a long time everything builds and it runs up.

`docker-compose --verbose build`
Does not give me much info.

Docker Engine - Community
Engine Version: 19.03.8

docker-compose version 1.25.4, build 8d51620a

```
root@someserver:/opt/containers/sites/somesite.nz# docker-compose --verbose build
compose.config.config.find: Using configuration files: ./docker-compose.yml
docker.utils.config.find_config_file: Trying paths: ['/root/.docker/config.json', '/root/.dockercfg']
docker.utils.config.find_config_file: No config file found
docker.utils.config.find_config_file: Trying paths: ['/root/.docker/config.json', '/root/.dockercfg']
docker.utils.config.find_config_file: No config file found
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "GET /v1.25/version HTTP/1.1" 200 862
compose.cli.command.get_client: docker-compose version 1.25.4, build 8d51620a
docker-py version: 4.1.0
CPython version: 3.7.5
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.0l  10 Sep 2019
compose.cli.command.get_client: Docker base_url: http+docker://localhost
compose.cli.command.get_client: Docker version: Platform={'Name': 'Docker Engine - Community'}, Components=[{'Name': 'Engine', 'Version': '19.03.8', 'Details': {'ApiVersion': '1.40', 'Arch': 'amd64', 'BuildTime': '2020-03-11T01:24:19.000000000+00:00', 'Experimental': 'false', 'GitCommit': 'afacb8b7f0', 'GoVersion': 'go1.12.17', 'KernelVersion': '4.15.0-108-generic', 'MinAPIVersion': '1.12', 'Os': 'linux'}}, {'Name': 'containerd', 'Version': '1.2.13', 'Details': {'GitCommit': '7ad184331fa3e55e52b890ea95e65ba581ae3429'}}, {'Name': 'runc', 'Version': '1.0.0-rc10', 'Details': {'GitCommit': 'dc9208a3303feef5b3839f4323d9beb36df0a9dd'}}, {'Name': 'docker-init', 'Version': '0.18.0', 'Details': {'GitCommit': 'fec3683'}}], Version=19.03.8, ApiVersion=1.40, MinAPIVersion=1.12, GitCommit=afacb8b7f0, GoVersion=go1.12.17, Os=linux, Arch=amd64, KernelVersion=4.15.0-108-generic, BuildTime=2020-03-11T01:24:19.000000000+00:00
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_network <- ('someproject_internal')
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "GET /v1.25/networks/someproject_internal HTTP/1.1" 404 68
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_network <- ('web')
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "GET /v1.25/networks/web HTTP/1.1" 200 None
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_network -> {'Attachable': False,
 'ConfigFrom': {'Network': ''},
 'ConfigOnly': False,
 'Containers': {'31db88fbbf7b3cc7da09559e024287424c4c689afdb0e924558583339233fec3': {'EndpointID': '798b82453ee5b309bccd5cb230e440bbbb79fe2b7746e668291cd88ca76b3c2f',
                                                                                     'IPv4Address': '172.19.0.3/16',
                                                                                     'IPv6Address': '',
                                                                                     'MacAddress': '02:42:ac:13:00:03',
                                                                                     'Name': 'someproject_someproject_1'},
                '405639a07d229936eabfd6a766a6ce053ca5647e11f06dec3d15413d5c230b5e': {'EndpointID': '2aec703aeb0a86ce68ffae4a042fc405be9996aa19d5c288701702fc40d4e486',
                                                                                     'IPv4Address': '172.19.0.10/16',
...
compose.project.build: es-someproject uses an image, skipping
compose.service.build: Building someproject
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker build <- (path='/opt/containers/sites/somesite.nz', tag='someproject_someproject', rm=True, forcerm=False, pull=False, nocache=False, dockerfile=None, cache_from=None, labels=None, buildargs={}, network_mode=None, target=None, shmsize=None, extra_hosts=None, container_limits={'memory': None}, gzip=False, isolation=None, platform=None)
```

Comment: If you are building your image with `docker build`, is it taking less time? If not, then it has nothing to do with your compose/context. Can you share the Dockerfile if my assumption is right? Perhaps there's some room for improvement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a .dockerignore file in your Docker Build Context (Same place as Dockerfile/docker-compose.yml if not specified)

Inside it put your directory/files to ignore from the Docker context.

e.g. for me it was

`html`

Which my docker-compose later maps in as a volume.

Or you can specify the Build context to use e.g. a folder containing what you need to add/use in the Dockerfile.
Any volumes for code/files that you want to map into the running container should not be in the same directory, or they should be in a .dockerignore.

The build context can be configured to another path in the docker-compose.yml

```
build:
  context: .
  dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

So you could have a docker directory as the context with the Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml outside of it, then have your src directory and other things elsewhere.

Comment: Docker context is directory where Dockerfile is. I told you before

Comment: First of all Docker context is a configuration that tells Docker CLI how to connect to Docker daemon. What you are manipulating is Docker build context. Since Docker CLI and Docker daemon do not have to on the same machine, once you start Docker build it sends all the files from the local directory you specified as context to the daemon - it can take a very long time if there are many files to send of if the files are large. That’s why you have the option to exclude files and/or folders if they’re not used. You needed to exclude `html`, because it’s not necessary for building the image.

Answer (score 6):

If you want the whole ouput from docker compose build you should use the `--progress` flag, and set it to `plain`, like so

```
docker compose build --progress plain
```

I would also consider adding the `--no-cache` flag to see the whole build of the image.

Reference: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/compose_build/#options

Answer (score 0):

That's why context is too large or deep.
Try to create an empty folder, move your docker-compose.yml and Dockerfile there, and then

```
docker-compose build
docker-compose up -d
```

The problem usually happens when your context has a lot of folders, symlinks, and/or is too deep. Context is where your Dockerfile is:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  your-srv:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image ...
```

Comment: context: . is not present in my docker-compose.yml it is a version '3'.
It just has ```build: ./```

If I put
build:
  context: .
  dockerfile: Dockerfile

There is no change.

Is my context the current directory with the docker-compose.yml?
Yes It has folders and files in the directory as well, but I want to volume map/use those in the container.

Comment: Your answer pointed me towards some googling, found github issue talking about .gitignore
made .gitignore contain html (my directory with the projects source code) now it seems to build very fast.

I guess docker must copy or go over all the files somehow in the context path, even if they are not being added in the Dockerfile?

Comment: Don’t you mean `.dockerignore`?

Comment: Yes sorry .dockerignore fixes it.